# Initialize a boost::accumulator_set at runtime

Tags: c++, boost, boost-accumulators

Is there a way to declare at runtime a `boost::accumulator_set` with features determined as runtime?
Something like:

```
accumulator_set *acc;

if (SomeUserInput1)
{
  acc = new accumulator_set< double, features< tag::min >>;
}

if (SomeUserInput2)
{
  acc = new accumulator_set< double, features< tag::min, tag::max, tag::mean, tag::... >>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. You would need to write a type-erased accumulator set wrapper. That would perform badly at runtime, which is why it isn't supported our off the box.