# What is the advantage of droppable accumulator in boost library in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-accumulators

I've recently read the User's Guide of `Boost.Accumulator` There is a chapter named "Droppable Accumulators" which illustrates how to use "accumulators that can be removed from the `accumulator_set<>`". The whole section was talking about how it might cause trouble. But why do we want to use droppable accumulators? What is the advantage of this feature?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps declaring accumulator_set with all possible and potentially useful features and then dropping unused ones according to end user runtime configuration to keep only required would be one of the scenarios. see also [Initialize a boost::accumulator_set at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462724/initialize-a-boostaccumulator-set-at-runtime)